# How to clear "Face sets"?

Tags: sculpting

I want to clear this at all. 
But unlike Mask, it is indelible.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the *Face Sets* menu, go to *Face Set from Visible*. As long as everything is visible, this should clear the existing face sets.

[image: face sets]

This turns everything in one single Face Set which is not shown colored:

[image]